# Update values of multiple Excel workbooks with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a lot of Excel worksheets with a lot of same values that I should update with new values periodically so I googled and found [Automate the Boring Stuff. Chapter 12 – Working with Excel Spreadsheets](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/).

My workbooks have a header from row 1 to 6 with a couple of images and some cells are merged. I followed the Chapter 12 and found a simple script that should do what I need, this is what I came up with

```
import openpyxl
from PIL import *

excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('V23 R.0.xlsx')

sheet = excelFile.get_sheet_by_name(u'Caratula')

thickness_update = {'12.7': 12.5,
                    '6.4': 6.35,
                    '7.9': 8.0,
                    '4.8': 4.75}

for rowNum in range(3, 30):
    nominalThickness = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=6).value
    if nominalThickness in thickness_update:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=6).value = thickness_update[nominalThickness]

excelFile.save('V23 R.1.xlsx')
```

I know the code in the Chapter 12 was intended to replace the values of column 2 based on the values of column 1 but I thought that my code should change the values of column 6 with the ones in *thickness_update* but it does nothing. The column 6 has the same four values in different orders.

To see if openpyxl was accessing to the .xlsx file correctly I did

```
sv = sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value
print sv
```

and it returned **None**. That happened whit whatever the cell I was asking for.

As I said before, the header has two images and I get the following warning message

```
/home/gval/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/header_footer.py:49: UserWarning: Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored
  warn("""Cannot parse header or footer so it will be ignored""")
/home/gval/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/drawings.py:50: UserWarning: wmf image format is not supported so the image is being dropped
  warn(msg)
```

**EDIT:** This is what the first rows looks like

```
Couple of images in a two merged cells |  Something |  Something 
Something |  Something    | Something  |  Something |  Something
Something in a merged cells            |  Something |  Something
```

The data can be some numbers and some alphanumeric inputs.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the Data of the first **3** Rows of the Spreadsheet

Comment: The warning is just telling you what's happening: the images are dropped because the library used cannot handle the Windows Metafile format.
Use `ws.iter_cols(min_col=6, max_col=6, min_row=3)` for more clarity in your code.

Comment: @stovfl I've edited the question, sorry for the poor table. I can't show the explicit data of each worksheet because of confidentiality agreement.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @sempiternal: The given data didn't help to clarify what you want to do. Are you aware. that you **loose** your `wmf` images after saving with `openpyxl`? Do you want to continue using `openpyxl` anyway.

Comment: @stovfl yes, I did notice that I loose the wmf images, is there another way to do what is intended?

Comment: @sempiternal: To add WMF read or write support to your application, use [`PIL.WmfImagePlugin.register_handler()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=wmf#wmf) to register a WMF handler. You have to patch `openpyxl` as well, **dropping** WMF is hardcoded, see [OpenPyXL - find_images](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/reader/drawings.html#find_images).