# How to supress UserWarings in Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, openpyxl, suppress-warnings

I get the UserWarning 'C:\Users...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\drawings.py:58: UserWarning: wmf image format is not supported so the image is being dropped warn(msg)'
How can I suppress this warning message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stovfl answered this question:

To add WMF read or write support to your application, use PIL.WmfImagePlugin.register_handler() to register a WMF handler. You have to patch openpyxl as well, dropping WMF is hardcoded, see [OpenPyXL - find_images](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/reader/drawings.html#find_images)

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733105/update-values-of-multiple-excel-workbooks-with-openpyxl)

Comment: what about macros? I have some macros and they are being dropped on wrirng a script to insert values to .xlsm files

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to read the file, the warning can be suppressed by setting the `read_only` keyword argument to `True`:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=<your file>, read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pillow supports wmf image file:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#wmf-emf

By default, PIL.open() will load the image at 72 dpi.

So, if you want to modify excel file with wmf image(s),
what you need to do is convert wmf image to supported formats (e.g. "png")
when loading image(s) in the _import_image(img) function of
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py":

```
def _import_image(img):
    if not PILImage:
        raise ImportError('You must install Pillow to fetch image objects')

    if not isinstance(img, PILImage.Image):
        img = PILImage.open(img)
    
    # This is the part you have to add (Start)
    try:
        if (img.format.lower() == "wmf"):
            fp = BytesIO()
            img.save(fp, format="png")
            img = PILImage.open(fp)
    except:
        None
    # This is the part you have to add (End)

    return img
```

This will allows you to modify the excel file with wmf image(s).
But note that the quality of the image might be visibly different compared to original image(s), since image format conversion takes place.